# jest doesn't understand flow types and object destructuring?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jestjs, flowtype

I keep on getting this error with flow types and jest:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnType' of undefined

  at builder (src/index.js:22:195)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__test__/index.spec.js:6:53)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

The following is my entire setup for this:

application code:

```
// @flow
type BuilderReturnType = {
    path: string,
    query: string
}

type BuilderOptionsType = {
    returnType?: string
}

export default function builder(path: string, {returnType = 'object'}: BuilderOptionsType): BuilderReturnType {
    const query = {};
    let queryResult = null;
    if (returnType === 'string') {
        queryResult = doSomething(query);
    }
    return {
        path,
        query: queryResult !== null ? queryResult : query
    }
}
```

`.babelrc` config:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015", "jest"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-flow-strip-types"
    ],
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "presets": [
                "es2015", "jest"
            ],
            "plugins": [
                "transform-object-rest-spread",
                "transform-flow-strip-types"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`jest.json` config:

```
{
  "bail": true,
  "verbose": true,
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 100,
      "functions": 100,
      "lines": 100,
      "statements": 100
    }
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
  }
}
```

It seems that there are issues with the method signature using destructuring and flow types at the same time (`BuilderOptionsType` object):

```
    export default function builder(path: string, {returnType = 'object'}: BuilderOptionsType): BuilderReturnType { ... }
```

If I change `{returnType = 'object'}` to `options` and then destructure within the method, it seems to work completely fine. With that in mind, is that the only way to allow for using `jest` and `flow` types together? I'd prefer to be able to destructure in the signature instead of inside the method body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your error, you could just not be passing the second argument to the function. If you call `builder('foo')`, you'll be attempting to destructure `returnType` off of `undefined`.

Either call it with the second arg: `builder('foo', {})`, or provide a default value for the argument:

```js
export default function builder(path: string, {returnType = 'object'}: BuilderOptionsType = {}): BuilderReturnType { ... }
```

Comment: ah, i thought `{returnType = 'object'}: BuilderOptionsType` was enough